# Wrongly inherited function return type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was working on a function that returns array with 2 entries, some value and a function. Simplified version looks like this:

```
export default function useAnimatedTiming(value: number) {
  return [value, () => null];
}
```

Typescript inherits return value of this function as:

> function useAnimatedTiming(value: number): (number | (() => null))[]

Where as I expected it to be something like

> function useAnimatedTiming(value: number): [number, () => null]

i.e. return array with ordered types. I might be doing something wrongly here, but how could I get this sort of type returned, because it would come in very handy when doing array desctructuring to get these values i.e.

```
const [myValue, myAction] = useAnimatedTiming(1);
```

`myAction()` returns following error at the moment because typescript sees it as number or function, as opposed to just function

Comment: you are looking for the word 'infer' not 'inherit'

Comment: `(number | (() => null))[]` is exactly what your function returns; `Array<(number | (() => null))>` should do the same i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not infer a tuple type (which is what you were expecting) from array literals unless it has to.

You have two choices, either spell out the return type:

```
export default function useAnimatedTiming(value: number): [number, () => null] {
  return [value, () => null];
}
```

Or you can create a function that will force the compiler to infer the type of the array literal as a tuple not an array:

```
export function tuple<T extends unknown[]>(...a: T) { 
  return a;
}
export default function useAnimatedTiming(value: number) { // return type inferred as  [number, () => null] 
  return tuple(value, () => null)
}
```